# Does Tensorflow server serve/support non-tensorflow based libraries like scikit-learn?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tensorflow-serving, tfx

Actually we are creating a platform to be able to put AI usecases in production. TFX is the first choice but what if we want to use non-tensorflow based libraries like scikit learn etc and want to include a python script to create models. Will output of such a model be served by tensorflow server. How can I make sure to be able to run both tensorflow based model and non-tensorflow based libraries and models in one system design. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned below is the procedure to **`Deploy`** and **`Serve`** a **`Sci-kit Learn Model`** in **`Google Cloud Platform`**.

First step is to Save/Export the SciKit Learn Model using the below code:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'model.joblib')
```

Next step is to upload the **`model.joblib`** file to **`Google Cloud Storage.`**

After that, we need to create our model and version, specifying that we are loading up a **`scikit-learn model`**, and select the **`runtime version`** of **`Cloud ML engine`**, as well as the version of **`Python`** that we used to export this model.

Next, we need to present the data to **`Cloud ML Engine`** as a simple array, encoded as a json file, like shown below. We can use **`JSON Library`** as well.

`print(list(X_test.iloc[10:11].values))`

Next, we need to run the below command to perform the Inference,

```
gcloud ml-engine predict --model $MODEL_NAME --version $VERSION_NAME --json-instances $INPUT_FILE
```

For more information, please refer [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-scikit-learn-models-at-scale-f632f86477b8).